# Built-in functions become temporarily unrecognizable in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, built-in

So I've got this MS Access 2010 database containing a report. The report invokes a calculated field using ABS(), references the [page] variable, and also calls a VBA procedure triggered by an On Format event. 
After successfully testing the form (i.e., it displays and prints correctly in print-preview), every time I open the database and run the report, I get #Name? in the fields where ABS() and [page] are referenced, and the On Format event tries to run but claims it can't find the associated VBA code.

But if I open the VBA editor, **do absolutely nothing**, and close the editor, the report runs perfectly as designed.

It appears the database is not loading the library of built-in functions at launch, as well as not finding the VBA code it supposed to when the trigger fires.  Somehow the mere act of opening the VBA editor fixes both issues!
Has anyone experienced this?  My other databases don't have this issue, and this seems to have appeared out of the blue.

Thanks.

Comment: check your VBA references. Sometimes removing and saving, opening and reapplying references solves this type of randomness.

Answer (score 0):

If recompiling doesn't work and you have the latest service pack and you've tried everything else then one solution is to make a blank database and import everything into it and compile.  Sometimes this trick works when you can't figure out what's wrong, and the message about not finding VBA code makes me suspect corruption.

Comment: Thanks JJ. I'm thinking you are right - the behavior is now intermittent. I have been able to get it to work eventually by "clicking" around, but I should try the transfer-the-objects-to-a-blank-database.